# Selecting all same html attributes with (different) values included in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, select, attributes

I'm using VSCode for html editing. In VSCode it's very easy to select same occurences of a piece of code. What i need is selecting all ocuurances of an html attribute (like class, aria-label, etc.) with different values. Here's an example:

I want to select all "aria-label" occurences with the values included. So these will be selected:

```
aria-label="Apple"
aria-label="Oranges"
aria-label="Multiple Fruit Names"
aria-label=""
...
```

Is there a way to do that in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that regex knowledge essential so for last couple of days i studied Regex101, this is what worked for me on this question.

```
aria-[a-zA-Z]*="[A-Za-z\s]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex for that:

`^aria-label="[^"]*"`

Explanation:

- '^' ... matches newline
- 'aria-label=' ... that's your "search word"
- '[^"]' ... any character
- '*' ... zero or more occurrences of stuff within the group

Don't forget to enable regex search in search dialog (see below):

[image]

This is a good starting point to grasp the regex magic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts .

Comment: better to use `^aria-label="[^"]*"`

Comment: rioV8 thank you, updated answer with your suggestion

Comment: Thanks for reply but somehow it doesn't work. I activated regex in vscode searchbox. It doesn't match any results. Here is a pen, and it says no match too: https://regex101.com/r/npLpaI/1

Comment: Okay, on your link there is no: "aria-label=" in the text, only "aria-....". What would you like to match?

Comment: If i could select everything beginning with "aria-" (and including the rest of the attribute and the value the value that belongs to it) it could be wonderful.

Comment: so you can use: `^aria-[^"]+="[^"]*"`